# Key 'namespace' ignored when generating genmodel

Tags: java, bpmn

I'm having problems when I try to generate the genmodel from my ecore model. I make an Ecore model based on the tutorials and the CustomTask example (using MetaData), but I get the following warnings :

-this ExtendedMetaData annotation detail will be ignored because the key 'namespace' is not recognized.
-this ExtendedMetaData annotation detail with key 'namespace' will be ignored because the feature isn't an element, attribute or group.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Could you please add some code snippets about how this error occurs?

Comment: in what follows the error: "this ExtendedMetaData annotation detail will be ignored because the key 'namespace' is not recognized".  And "this ExtendedMetaData annotation detail with key 'namespace' will be ignored because the feature isn't an element, attribute or group."